# Geometry Nodes - Move points from other Splines using proximity

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, splines

I have a horizontal curve (red node in below image), which is instanced on a vertical curve (green node in below image).
The vertical curve has 3 points (ID 0, 1, 2) and the horizontal curve is instanced on point 1.

[image: node_setup]

[image: curves]

When I translate point 1 using the Set Position node, I would like to either:

- Translate point 0 of the *horizontal* curve by the same amount

Or (even more ideally):

- Translate the entire horizontal curve by the same amount

In effect, I would like to 'parent' the horizontal curve to the point on the vertical on which it was instanced.

Alternatively, when I translate a point on the vertical curve using the set position node, I would like to somehow 'grab' any points (from other curves) within a specific proximity (i.e. point 0 from the horizontal curve, which overlaps).

Please note, I am aware that I could use the set position node on the vertical curve **before** instancing the horizontal curve.

I am also aware that I could convert the curves (once joined) into a mesh, merge by distance, then convert back into a curve.

For reasons too complicated to explain, neither of these options are viable for the node setup I am working on.

I have no issue with realizing the horizontal curve instance (using the Realize Instances node), if required.

I hope I've explained the problem clearly. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just use another `Set Position` node at the instanced horizontal curve, and use the same offset there as at point 1 of the vertical curve?

Comment: Hello again quellenform :) Good question. The reason is because I actually intend to instance the vertical curve many times on another 'master' curve, I also intend to have many instances of the horizontal curve on the vertical. I just tried to simplify for this example. The plan is to realize ALL instances (horizontal and vertical), then randomize the positions of all points to introduce some distortion. However, when introducing this 'distortion' I need the horizontal curves to remain connected to the vertical.

Comment: Just to clarify:  I am instancing many versions of the horizontal curves onto the vertical curve, and then instancing many versions of the vertical curve (with the horizontal curves attached) onto a master curve.

I am then realizing the instances in order to introduce **variable** distortion across all of the curves. I can obviously isolate the 'root' of the vertical curves using ID = 0 so that they do not appear to 'disconnect' from the master curve, but I have no way to keep the horizontal curves connected to the verticals.

Comment: OK, so far I understand this now, but I still can't quite picture it. Can you add a concrete example where you show this (blend file)? The way it sounds to me, it should be solvable by marking certain curves/points with `Capture Attribute` and a little selection logic, but that's just a guess now.

Comment: Certainly, I'll be happy to put something together. I'll try to get it uploaded this evening but I may need to step away shortly. Thanks!!

Comment: I hope this attached file helps to clarify. I'd be interested in any thoughts you might have :) [.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3f0cahcyq7qzamn/curve_problem1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: you wrote: "Or (even more ideally):

Translate the entire horizontal curve by the same amount
In effect, I would like to 'parent' the horizontal curve to the point on the vertical on which it was instanced." -> these are two different things. Parenting means, it would rotate as well with the parent object. What do you want now? Translating + rotation or just translation?

Comment: Either would be fine. I'm not rotating the points, I'm only translating them using Set Position, so in effect all I'm interested in is translation. If I can achieve that through some kind of parenting operation, that would be absolutely acceptable.